# How to decode opus audio from memory

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, opus

I'm working with audio in dart/flutter web. I have a stream of audio bytes encoded in opus that I need to decode in order to do stuff.
I've been googling a bit and haven't found much options, only [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/opus_dart/score), which I'm trying to use, but I can't even get to compile a simplified version of what it seems to be its only example.
Are there any other options?

this is the simplified example.

```
import 'package:opus_flutter/opus_flutter.dart' as opus_flutter;
import 'package:opus_dart/opus_dart.dart';

 static Future<Uint8List> decodeOpus(
    Stream<Uint8List> input, int sampleRate) async {
    List<Uint8List> output = [];
    await input.transform(StreamOpusDecoder.bytes(
          floatOutput: false,
          sampleRate: sampleRate,
          channels: 1,
          copyOutput: true,
          forwardErrorCorrection: false))
      .cast<Uint8List>()
      .forEach(output.add);
    return output[0];
  }
```

it's error in case anyone know the package

```
The argument type 'StreamOpusDecoder' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<Uint8List, dynamic>'.
```

Comment: VLCPlayer maybe? It's a huge dependency though

Comment: Why are you using `StreamOpusDecoder` when you could be using one of the simpler decoders? In your app do you know where the packet boundaries are? I think you are misunderstanding what the stream decoder does. It processes a stream of packets (each a Uint8List) into a stream of outputs (each a list of num - representing the PCM). In the code above you just have a single byte array (which I guess contains more than 1 packet)

Comment: @RichardHeap Because I don't know and couldn't find simpler decoders, mind suggesting one? I'm working with mono channel, and what I want is given a stream of input, obtain a stream of output representing PCM

Comment: As in, from the same package, https://pub.dev/documentation/opus_dart/latest/opus_dart/SimpleOpusDecoder-class.html

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks! now at least compiles. According to the readme of the package, if I'm using Flutter, I can use opus_flutter to obtain a dynamic library instead of providing one myself. Is this correct or I am misunderstanding something? I am now trying to use SimpleOpusRecorder but there seems to be an allocation memory problem because when I call its method decode, it throws a OpusException -1: invalid argument

Comment: Work through the example code carefully and raise any issues with the developer.